# How to call methods that inject parameters in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit

There is a pattern which is widely used in my current project:

```
private Collection<Converter<T>> converters = new HashSet<>();

@Inject
private void init(@Any Instance<Converter<T>> converters) {
    for (Converter<T> converter : converters) {
        this.converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

This way I can create as many converters as I want and they are automatically injected to my bean.

My problem is now with testing: the converters collection is used in my code, but Junit doesn't call the `init(..)` method and I need to call it to set the mocked converters.

I could make the method protected, but I don't feel OK with it because I would be changing the visibility scope of the method.

I could also call the method using reflection, but this also doesn't feel right.

This brings me to the conclusion that this code could be improved to be more testable.

Is there anyway I change this code so the testability is improved but the references are still automatically injected?

Comment: Why do you need to proceed like this anyway? why not keeping Instance<Converter<T>> as type of your field converters and inject it into the field directly?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto doing so would create a new instance of my Converter on each iterator over the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead and make it 'public' or 'protected'.

You are not actually gaining any protection from someone changing the collection post-instantiation this way (you've just made it a little more awkward), so you don't lose anything by exposing that method (in fact I'd argue you make your class slightly better, because than you let people chose how they want to construct, rather than forcing a use of injection/reflection).

If you did want to fully prevent post-instantiation modification, than you're going to have to go to a 'final' variable anyway, with an unmodifiable collection type and change to constructor injection, but I don't get the impression that this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is: if you can't "trust" the people who can write code within your "package" ... I guess having "private" on a method doesn't really help you anyway. Because if people want to mess up, and they can write code in your package, they will find ways to mess up anyway.

Meaning: if you drop the "private" on your method, yes it becomes package-visible. But you can place a javadoc on it that says: "Don't call directly; used for unit test/auto-wiring only" or something like that.